# Problems with FusedLocationAPI on device without Cell Service

Tags: android, android-location

I'm testing an Android app on a device that has a SIM card with no cell service. I have both "coarse" and "fine" location APIs turned on via the manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
```

Here's the code with which I'm initializing the GoogleApiClient via an inherited method for the activity:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.*;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

....

protected GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
protected boolean locationServicesIsAvailable = false;
protected Location lastKnownLocation;

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

protected Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    if(googleApiClient == null) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        return null;
    } else
        return LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    locationServicesIsAvailable = true;
    // @TODO signal the rest of the app that current location is now available
    lastKnownLocation = getLastKnownLocation();
    API.log("Geo location reported! => " + lastKnownLocation.toString());
}
```

The problem appears to be that the `onConnected()` callback isn't firing, even with GPS enabled on the device. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you calling googleApiClient.connect() after building it?

Comment: Yeah, @DanielNugent has a point. From the docs: "With the callback interfaces defined, you're ready to call connect(). To gracefully manage the lifecycle of the connection, you should call connect() during the activity's onStart() (unless you want to connect later), then call disconnect() during the onStop() method."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured I'd post an answer to close this out - thanks Daniel & CaseyB! The problem was that I was wiring up the API client but didn't call the `connect()` method. Adding this line in the `buildGoogleApiClient()` method, right after the `build()` chain call on the `googleApiClient` was the fix:

```
googleApiClient.connect();
```

You could also chain in the `connect()` call after `build()`.